# Why can't I change text of select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have an html select with options inside. With jQuery I'm able to select and read option's text but I'm unable to modify it using either .html('my_text') and .text('my_text).

Here is my HTML :

```
<select id="select_format_date" name="select_format_date">
    <option id='0' value="0">jj/mm/yyyy</option>
    <option id='1' value="1">jj mm</option>
    <option id='2' value="2">jj month short</option>
    <option id='3' value="3">jj month full</option>
</select>
```

And here are my attemps to modify their texts with jQuery :

```
alert($("#select_format_date option[id='0']").text());
$("#select_format_date option[id='0']").text('TEST');
$("#select_format_date option[id='0']").html('TEST');
```

As said the alert display the option's text correctly so the selector is good but I can't modify the text I don't understand why, my jQuery is in a `$(document).ready(function() {})` so the DOM should be fully loaded. Both HTML and jQuery are in the same file. I also tried to add the `.change()` but didn't work.

Any ideas of what could cause that ?

Thanks for you time reading and helping.

EDIT

Problem solved I had a plugin `.jqTransform` messing up with my html, thanks for you time !!

Comment: When do you want to change the text of select?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. The code works fine for me. Possibly the `select` is populated asynchronously, and your code runs before that happens.

Comment: When the DOM is fully loaded. I have my `$(document).ready(function() {})` with all my jQuery first in my file then I have my HTML.

I just implemented the select there is nothing using it yet apart my jQuery shown in my post.

Comment: OK, but how is the `select` populated? Do you see the values when you do "view source" on the page? Or only when you inspect the element with dev tools?

Comment: please set up a plnkr or jsfiddle. That would help us in understanding and debugging the problem.

Comment: Select is populated with options non dynamicaly. I can see my select populated both in source file and inspect element

Comment: @Shaik Mahaboob Basha  ok I gonna try to set it up

Comment: There is something in your code which is again changing the value.....otherwise `.text` works fine

Comment: Ok as @trincot said this thing is working fine in the jsfiddle, I gonna investigate about "populated asynchronously, and your code runs before that happens" and I will keep this post updated

Comment: @Folder All seems to work fine for me too. You get the alert of the original text and the new text, you can also see it change in the select. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/m3rf7qw5/) Maybe check the browser console for errors and if you see any share them in your question.

Comment: I should have tried the jsFiddle first sorry for that, I don't know where it could come from then, I gonna investigate trying to switch things from places ..

Comment: maybe you got some duplicate ID used.. try search id="0"

Comment: No duplicates found, and the only thing interacting with this select is the jQuery posted in my original post

Comment: @Folder could you provide a full copy of what you are working with PasteBin? I think this might be the only way to help you from this point. [**Paste Bin**](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Problem is fixed (dunno how to mark my post as solved), it was coming from a js lib call I didn't knew about see my edit :) Thanks for your time again :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the below snippet, both `.text()` and `.html()` worked for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert($("#select_format_date option[id='0']").text());
 //$("#select_format_date option[id='0']").text('TEST');
 $("#select_format_date option[id='0']").html('TEST');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_format_date" name="select_format_date">
    <option id="0" value="0">jj/mm/yyyy</option>
    <option id="1" value="1">jj mm</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">jj month short</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">jj month full</option>
</select>
```

Maybe your jQuery is not loaded or some error may stop the parse process somewhere in the rest of your code?

Comment: `jQuery` must be loading if *" the alert display the option's text correctly so the selector is good*" is working.

Comment: Thanks for your time I should have tried jsFiddle first, the problem must come from something else but I doesnt understand why I could read it but not change it if there was a problem with jQuery not loading (which is not the case because I use it a lot for other stuff in my page) gonna investigate keeping this post updated

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to define a id for your options, just try this

```
("#select_format_date").val('value').change();
```

this is a fastest and simple way to change the selected value and text of select tag with jquery in my opinion.